# Integration issue (seems simple ...) with $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to compute this integral:

$$\int_{1}^2 \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x} dx$$

But I'm confused on how to do this since I'm aware that $e^{-x^2}$ has no integrand.

Comment: But you know that you can easily find an antiderivative of $xe^{-x^2}$, right?

Comment: The indefinite integral can be expressed as $\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Ei}(-x^2)$, where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: Yes, the antiderivative would be $\frac{-e^{-x^2}}{2}$, although I'm not sure how much that helps me ... but I may be forgetting something as it's been a while since I did some serious integration. Also, thanks for the link (and post edit) Vargas, but I've never seen that exponential integral, so I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Actually I just looked this up ... I don't think it can be solvable outside of using Ei ..

Comment: $\ln(2)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{2^{2k} -1}{(2k)k!}$.

Comment: The first 30 terms sum to 0.10780229099283571 using a quick Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral is not elementary. 
Change variables. 
Let $z=x^2$. 
Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
I &=& \int_1^2 dx\,  x^{-1} e^{-x^2} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \int_1^4 dx\, z^{-1} e^{-z} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \left(\int_1^\infty dx\, z^{-1} e^{-z} - \int_4^{\infty} dx\, z^{-1} e^{-z}\right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}[\mathrm{E}_1(1) - \mathrm{E}_1(4)] \\
&=& 0.10780\cdots
\end{eqnarray}$$
where the integral $\mathrm{E}_1(x)$ is closely related to the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$. 
(This can in fact be rewritten as $\frac{1}{2}\left[\mathrm{Ei}(-4) - \mathrm{Ei}(-1)\right]$.)
An integral such as this cannot be written in terms of simple functions---this is as simple as it gets!

Comment: @user16647: Glad to help. It looks like copper.hat has the correct infinite series in the comments above.